# How to detect and match indentation size of current buffer

Tags: indentation, web-mode, javascript

I'm working on a javascript project that has inconsistent tab sizes 2spaces vs 4spaces on the server and client. I'm using `web-mode` for javascript editing. I'm looking for a feature like SublimeTexts `detect_indentation`

I have tried: 
https://github.com/emacsmirror/fuzzy-format
https://github.com/jscheid/dtrt-indent

And neither have worked

Comment: I've had some success with dtrt-indent and ``javascript-mode`` when using Spacemacs. It doesn't look like they have bindings yet for ``web-mode``, but if you know what variables it would need to override, it probably wouldn't be difficult to add.

Comment: have a try with https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/fuzzy-format.el

Comment: It seems that `dirt-indent` isn't aware of variables used by `web-mode`, so it would need having them added to support it.

Comment: "...neither have worked" -- please describe specifically what you have done, and detail what isn't working (what you expect, and what actually happens) with examples.  Without this information, the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As Python allows to change the indent blockwise, there is related stuff in Python-modes.

python-mode.el uses `py-guess-indent-offset`, built-in python.el uses `python-indent-guess-indent-offset`

Wondering how many people are interested in generalising these proceedings.